# Storing node attributes by name in igraph for subsetting plots

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking

I am working with a large social network that spans 5 years of data collection. My intention is to subset the data by month/year to analyze the change in various network metrics.
I want to store node attributes into the data frame such that they can be called back after subsetting. For the reproducible example, I want to subset my global network by weight (e.g. all nodes with edges >2).

Is there a way to store node attributes (i.e. Male/Female) into the nodes on the original (larger data frame) that can be recalled after filtering out various nodes (and ignored if the node is missing)? Meaning, if a node's order was changed in the df it will still be associated with the correct sex (i.e. node 1 is always a male regardless if other nodes have been removed or reordered).

I've found answers to creating node attributes for each individual sub-network but I need to generate ~50 subnetworks and being forced to label each individual networks node, in the correct order would be hours of extra work. (e.g. `V(any.given.subnetwork)$Sex <- c("male","female","male","male","female","male"))`.

Very small reproducible example below to illustrate my code:

```
 library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(dplyr)
#Load Global Data
set.seed(43)
df <- data.frame(id=1:6,id2=c(2,3,4,5,6,1), weight= c(4,3,1,8,2,7))

#make an igraph graph from the df dataframe
df.df <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE)

#make df.df and adjacency matrix
df.mat <- as_adjacency_matrix(df.df, type = "both", names = TRUE,
                                        sparse = FALSE, attr= "weight")

#make it an igraph object
df.mat <- graph.adjacency(df.mat, mode= "directed", weighted=TRUE, diag = FALSE)

summary(df.mat)

#Applying "sex" attribute to the nodes
V(df.mat)$Sex <- c("male","female","male","male","female","male")

#Plot
ggraph(df.mat, layout = "nicely") +
geom_edge_link(aes(alpha= weight)) + geom_node_point(aes(color = factor(Sex))) 


#filtering out any nodes from Global "df" that have a weight less than 2
df.mat.01 <- df %>%
  filter(weight > 2)  

#make an igraph graph from the df.01 dataframe
df.df.01 <- graph.data.frame(df.mat.01, directed = TRUE)
#make df.df.01 and adjacency matrix
df.mat01 <- as_adjacency_matrix(df.df.01, type = "both", names = TRUE,
                                sparse = FALSE, attr= "weight")
#make it an igraph object
df.mat01 <- graph.adjacency(df.mat01, mode= "directed", weighted=TRUE, diag = FALSE)

ggraph(df.mat01, layout = "nicely") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(alpha= weight)) + geom_node_point(aes(color = factor(Sex))) 
#Error in factor(Sex) : object 'Sex' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `tidygraph` makes such manipulations straightforward. You can convert your graph into a `tbl_graph` which is easier to manipulate, and can be plotted directly with `ggraph` or converted back to an `igraph`:

```r
library(tidygraph)

df_mat <- as_tbl_graph(df.mat)

df_mat
#> # A tbl_graph: 6 nodes and 6 edges
#> #
#> # A directed simple graph with 1 component
#> #
#> # Node Data: 6 x 2 (active)
#>   name  Sex   
#>   <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 1     male  
#> 2 2     female
#> 3 3     male  
#> 4 4     male  
#> 5 5     female
#> 6 6     male  
#> #
#> # Edge Data: 6 x 3
#>    from    to weight
#>   <int> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     2      4
#> 2     2     3      3
#> 3     3     4      1
#> # ... with 3 more rows
```

For example, to filter out all edges with weight <= 2 and plot with ggraph, we can do:

```r
df_mat %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  filter(weight > 2) %>%
  ggraph(layout = "nicely") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(alpha= weight)) + 
  geom_node_point(aes(color = factor(Sex)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful for future subplots but unfortunately, I have already made subplots through filtering for most of the networks as seen in the reproducible example. I was hoping to find a function that allows me to basically run the node attributes through the global data just once, then recall that function on various subsets to apply it to the matching notes with the same name (I think `lapply` can be used but not sure how). I appreciate the answer and going forward will be sure to use the `as_tbl_graph` function when subsetting plots in the future

Comment: In your example you can add an attribute to the dataframe as follows: `df$Sex <- c("male", "female", "male", "male", "male", "female", "male")`.

If the first column contains duplicate ids, then the id and the corresponding attributes should be merged.